# Does converting IRA to Roth count toward contribution limit?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, roth-conversion

I have a small balance in a traditional IRA (as a result of company-match to Roth 401K contribution) and also a Roth IRA which is fully funded for the year.

Can I pay the tax and convert my traditional IRA to Roth IRA despite the fact that I've already contributed the annual maximum into my Roth IRA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can convert an unlimited amount from a traditional IRA to a Roth, and pay the tax to the extent any of the account wasn't yet taxed. It does not count against any annual deposit limits.